# Terminal view to not display computations

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new to coding in python and I am trying to setup shop in VS Code to do so. I have got to the below view which is easy enough to start practicing with the language.

Although, I'd like the terminal window on the right to behave like Python Shell where it displays directly the result of the code without showing all computations and all formula by formula steps. Is that possible?

[image]

```
import pprint
message = 'something has to be said.'
count = {}

for character in message.upper():
    count.setdefault(character,0)
    count[character] = count[character]+1

pprint.pprint(count)
```

Comment: It is better to put code in text, because it is hard to copy the text from the image.

Comment: as for me on image it already runs `Python Shell` - and standard `Python Shell` always shows computation if it runs line by line. Maybe better use normal terminal with `shell` instead of `Python` which will run it as `python script.py` and it will display only `print()`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with `furas`.

You can choose `Run Python File in Terminal` command, it will be like this:

[image]

And you can try to install the `Coder Runner` extension, it will be like this:

[image]

Or take the shortcut of `F5` to run it in debug mode is also recommended:

[image]